# How do I dynamically update a C++ ListView?

Tags: c++, user-interface, listview, winapi

I'm looking to insert data into a Listview on an event (e.g. new message received) rather than through a button click. This means that throughout the runtime of the software, rows will be continually added and deleted.

How do I go about doing this? I can add rows when I create the ListView e.g.

```
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.iItem = 0;
lvi.iSubItem = 0;
lvi.pszText = bob;

ListView_InsertItem(list, &lvi);
```

But I don't know which windows message handler I would need to put this in if I wanted to update on-the-fly. E.g. does it go in WM_PAINT? WM_NOTIFY? Etc.

I'm using the Win32 listview without MFC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a timer and make your modifications when that timer fires

Comment: [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx) maybe?

Comment: @Axalo Why call `UpdateWindow`?

Comment: Thanks David, I've just updated the question. It doesn't need to be on timer, it would be when a certain event happens. But my question is how you update that particular control. Do you need to put the code in a certain event handler? E.g. WM_NOTIFY?

Comment: I suggest you update the list when that certain event happens. Presumably you know what that event happens to be.

Comment: So does that mean I can update (insert/delete) from anywhere in my class? Previously, I've been attempting to do this in the WM_PAINT case of my WndProc callback without success.

Comment: Your mental model is all borked. There is no C++ in the Windows API. It's plain C, and you can learn about it [here](http://winprog.org/tutorial/).

Comment: I think you are getting confused. Update the list when this event occurs. IIRC, that will be enough to invalidate the control and so force a paint cycle. If the control is not invalidated, do so yourself with `InvalidateRect`.

Comment: You dont need to `invalidate` or `UpdateWindow` the listview. It will be done automatically.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε thank you, I thought that was so, I just could not remember

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. `ListView_InsertItem` is just a macro for sending a `LVM_INSERTITEM` message to listview control, so it knows it has to draw itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over thinking this. Simply modify the list whenever your timer fires (or some other event). The rest list view control knows it needs to be re-painted and so will invalidate itself. This will provoke a paint cycle and the list view window will therefore get asked to paint itself.

Comment: OK thanks for your help David. I understand. However, I have tried to call insert at the next element from a method within the same class and it still fails to update the ListView. I can add elements to the ListView without any problems as long as I do it in the same method as I have created the columns. I'm not sure what the problem could be, I'm using the global handle HWND that was used to create the window.

Comment: You are probably getting the params wrong in your call to ListView_InsertItem. Start by adding the error checking that is not present in the question.

Comment: Interesting. When I try to add an element with iItem = 1, the macro returns 0. There should already be an item at that index from where I created the columns. The original item stays the same in the form, but the new item doesn't get added. Is this a display issue?

Comment: That would happen if you have an empty list. I posit that there are more than one list and you are adding to the wrong one. It's no fun guessing like this. I think I answered the question you asked. If you can't solve it from here I suspect you need a new question.

Comment: You were right David. It turns out I was initialising the HWND locally but using a member HWND!